# Windows Phone 8 Open Map to Current Location

Tags: maps, windows-phone-8

In Windows Phone 8 I want to open the native maps app to the users current location.

The closest I came to this was the [MapsTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.mapstask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). The description makes me believe it's perfect:

> Allows an application to launch the Maps application centered at the
>   location specified with the Center property or at the **user’s current
>   location**. If SearchTerm is set, locations matching the search term are
>   tagged on the map.

If you don't supply a Center, it uses the users current location. Perfect! But if you don't supply a center, and don't supply a SearchTerm, it throws an exepction (by design).

So I have to supply a SearchTerm. But if I put something that isn't local to the user, I get a popup that says "No Results: We couldn't find any matches for your search. Try a different spelling or search term".

Now I could get the users location myself and launch the map with that location, but that feels wrong considering the Maps App already does it for you. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to get the Geolocation youself and send it to the map task. Use GeoLocator one-time geolocation acquisition to do that.

```cs
private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var geoLocator = new Geolocator();
    var geoloc = await geoLocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
    new MapsTask()
    {
        Center = new GeoCoordinate(geoloc.Coordinate.Latitude, geoloc.Coordinate.Longitude),
        ZoomLevel = 10
    }.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Wrote a Tutorial On getting Current Location That gets You the one shot location with which you can map out.

```
private async void GetCurrentLocation()
￼{
    ￼Geolocator locationFinder = new Geolocator
￼    {
￼        DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 50,
￼        DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.Default
    ￼};
    try
    {
        Geoposition currentLocation = await  locationFinder.GetGeopositionAsync(
            maximumAge: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
            timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            String longitude = currentLocation.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString("0.00");
            String latitude = currentLocation.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString("0.00");
            ￼MyTextBlock.Text = "Long: " + longitude + "Lat: " + latitude;
￼    }
￼    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
￼    {
￼       MessageBox.Show("And Exception Occured");
￼    }
}
```

See The Link Below For Full Content With Demo File
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/windows/windows-phone-8-sdk-geolocation-services/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.